# Copying data between metal textures of different shapes

Tags: swift, keras, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I am converting two trained Keras models to Metal Performance Shaders. I have to reshape the output of the first graph and use it as input to the second graph. The first graph's output is an MPSImage with "shape" (1,1,8192), and the second graph's input is an MPSImage of "shape" (4,4,512).

I cast graph1's output image.texture as a float16 array, and pass it to the following function to copy the data into "midImage", a 4x4x512 MPSImage:

```
func reshapeTexture(imageArray:[Float16]) -> MPSImage{

    let image = imageArray
    image.withUnsafeBufferPointer { ptr in
        let width = midImage.texture.width
        let height = midImage.texture.height
        for slice in 0..<128{
            for w in 0..<width{
                for h in 0..<height{
                    let region = MTLRegion(origin: MTLOriginMake(w, h, 0),
                                           size: MTLSizeMake(1, 1, 1))
                    midImage.texture.replace(region: region, mipmapLevel: 0, slice: slice, withBytes: ptr.baseAddress!.advanced(by: ((slice * 4 * width * height) + ((w + h) * 4)), bytesPerRow: MemoryLayout<Float16>.stride * 4, bytesPerImage: 0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return midImage
}
```

When I pass midImage to graph2, the output of the graph is a square with 3/4 garbled noise, 1/4 black in the bottom right corner. I think I am not understanding something about the MPSImage slice property for storing extra channels. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Metal 2d texture arrays are nearly always stored in a Morton or “Z” ordering of some kind. Certainly MPS always allocates them that way, though I suppose on MacOS there may be a means to make a linear 2D texture array and wrap a MPSImage around it. So, without undue care, direct access of a 2d texture array backing store is going to result in sadness and confusion.

The right way to do this is to write a simple Metal copy kernel. This gives you storage order independence and you don’t have to wait for the command buffer to complete before you can do the operation.

A feature request in Radar might also be warranted. Please also look in the latest macOS / iOS seed to see if Apple recently added a reshape filter for you.